# How to populate array element defined inside the class

Tags: c#

How to populate array element defined inside the class? I would like to Populate List of student with array of Marks,which i am not able to locate .

```
public class Marks
{
   public int ENG  { get; set; }
   public int MATHS { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
   public string empName { set; get; }
   public string empAddress { set; get; }
   public Marks[] StudentMarks { set; get; }
}

var objs = new List<Student>() 
{
   new Employee() {empName = "Manish" empAddress = "MUM"....array element with Marks of two subjects
   new Employee() {empName = "Manoj", empAddress = "MUM"....arrayelement with Marks of two subjects
}
```

Comment: There is no Employee class

Comment: Are you using arrays for some kind of requirement? If not, why not using a List? PS: Is Student a typo for Employee?

Comment: A tip: take the effort to create a small project for a question and copy/paste correct, compiling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to initialize array in a single line you should use one of the following code

```
int[] n1 = new int[4] {2, 4, 6, 8};
int[] n2 = new int[] {2, 4, 6, 8};
int[] n3 = {2, 4, 6, 8};
```

In your case, you should populate your array with Marks objects.

```
Marks[] MarksArray =  new [] {new Marks() {ENG = 1, MATHS = 1}, new Marks() {ENG = 2, MATHS = 2}};
```

This array contains 2 marks - `new Marks() {ENG = 1, MATHS = 1}` and  `new Marks() {ENG = 2, MATHS = 2}`.

You can read find more examples here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601(v=vs.71).aspx

So you can create your objects this way

```
  var objs = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student() {empName = "Manish", empAddress = "MUM", StudentMarks =  new [] {new Marks() {ENG = 1, MATHS = 1}, new Marks() {ENG = 2, MATHS = 2}} },
                new Student() {empName = "Manish", empAddress = "MUM", StudentMarks =  new [] {new Marks() {ENG = 1, MATHS = 1}, new Marks() {ENG = 2, MATHS = 2}} },
            };
```

Comment: does this create two array objects? I don't understand this... can you explain a little?

Answer (score 0):

If you were concerned with the syntax only then this would do:

```
void Main()
{
  var objs = new List<Employee>()
{
   new Employee() {
    empName = "Manish",
    empAddress = "MUM",
    StudentMarks = new Marks[] {
      new Marks {ENG=10, MATHS = 100},
      new Marks { ENG=20, MATHS = 80}, }},
   new Employee() {
  empName = "Manoj",
  empAddress = "MUM",
  StudentMarks = new Marks[] {
      new Marks { ENG=59, MATHS = 40},
      new Marks { ENG=60, MATHS = 80},
      new Marks { ENG=80, MATHS = 10},
      new Marks { MATHS = 90},
      new Marks { ENG=70},}
  },
};

foreach (var student in objs)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", student.empName, student.empAddress);
  foreach (var mark in student.StudentMarks)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Eng:{0}, Maths:{1}", mark.ENG, mark.MATHS);
  }
}
}

public class Marks
{
  public int ENG { get; set; }
  public int MATHS { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
  public string empName { set; get; }
  public string empAddress { set; get; }
  public Marks[] StudentMarks { set; get; }
}

public class Employee : Student
{ }
```

However, that is not a good model. A better model would be like this:

```
void Main()
{
  var objs = new List<Student>()
 {
   new Student() {
    Name = "Manish",
    Address = "MUM",
    StudentMarks = new List<Mark> {
      new Mark {Name="Eng", Score = 50},
      new Mark {Name="Maths", Score = 60},
      }
    },
new Student() {
    Name = "Manoj",
    Address = "MUM",
    StudentMarks = new List<Mark> {
      new Mark {Name="Maths", Score = 100},
      new Mark {Name="Eng", Score = 80},
      new Mark {Name="Eng", Score = 70},
      new Mark {Name="Eng", Score = 90},
      new Mark {Name="Maths", Score = 90},
      }
    },
 };

  foreach (var student in objs)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", student.Name, student.Address);
    foreach (var mark in student.StudentMarks)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}, Score:{1}", mark.Name, mark.Score);
    }
  }
}

public class Mark
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Score { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
  public string Name { set; get; }
  public string Address { set; get; }
  public List<Mark> StudentMarks { set; get; }
}
```

This one is still not very good. A better one might be:

```
void Main()
{
  var objs = new List<Student>()
 {
new Student() {
    Name = "Manish",
    Address = "MUM",
    StudentMarks = new Dictionary<string,List<int>> {
      {"Maths", new List<int> {60,70,50}},
      {"Eng", new List<int> {80,70,90}},
      }
    },
new Student() {
    Name = "Manoj",
    Address = "MUM",
    StudentMarks = new Dictionary<string,List<int>> {
      {"Maths", new List<int> {70,90}},
      {"Eng", new List<int> {40,50,60,60}},
      }
    },
 };
  foreach (var student in objs)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", student.Name, student.Address);
    foreach (var course in student.StudentMarks)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Course:{0}, Average:{1}", course.Key, course.Value.Average());
      foreach (var score in course.Value)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(score); 
      }
    }
  }
}

public class Mark
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Score { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
  public string Name { set; get; }
  public string Address { set; get; }
  public Dictionary<string,List<int>> StudentMarks { set; get; }
}
```

And there are better ones.